# How can we insert the column name from one table into a another table as row using java script

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create table test(columnname varchar(100))


CREATE or replace TABLE brand(
    Brand VARCHAR(150),
    Day DATE,
    Users    VARCHAR(150)
   );

SELECT array_agg(column_name)
FROM information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'brand';
```

using this query i am getting a single line, but to insert it as row

excepted output:

```
select * from test
```

| columnname |
| --- |
| Brand |
| Day |
| Users |

Comment: What is your actual expected output?  Text?  A SQL table?  Something else?

Comment: Where is the JavaScript part?

Answer (score 0):

If you want many values from you ‘test’ table when you select from the information schema don't use array_agg to turn the many rows into a single line.

To insert:

```
insert into test
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'brand';
```